# How to use for loop with promise

Tags: javascript

I want to make asyncrous for loop with promise.
So I write a code below.

```
const fetchData = function (num) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (num === 0) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(num);
      }, 3000);
    }
    if (num !== 0) {
      resolve(num);
    }
  });
};

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i += 1) {
  fetchData(i).then((i) => {
    console.log(i);
  });
}
```

And I want to get the result ,

```
0
1
2
```

however, I got,

```
1
2
0
```

How can I use properly use promise in the for loop?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Remove if statements and this code work normally

Comment: @MuradSofiyev - hardly the point

Comment: If you want `0` to be resolved first, why do you set a 3 second timeout to resolve `0`?

Comment: chain the promises or use async/await to process each iteration in sequence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using async/await makes it simple

Note the IIFE, because you need a function `async` to use `await`

```js
const fetchData = function(num) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (num === 0) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(num);
      }, 3000);
    }
    if (num !== 0) {
      resolve(num);
    }
  });
};
(async() => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i += 1) {
    await fetchData(i).then((i) => {
      console.log(i);
    });
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) would give you that result:

```js
const fetchData = function(num) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (num === 0) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(num);
      }, 3000);
    }
    if (num !== 0) {
      resolve(num);
    }
  });
};

Promise.all([0, 1, 2].map(fetchData)).then(console.log);
```